# how to add not null column in existing table and then insert values in that column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ddl, alter-table

how to add not null column in existing table and then insert values in that column ??
in sql...

Comment: Which database server are you using? Microsoft SQL Server, MySql, etc?

Comment: If table has data, you can't. You have to add it as Null then populate the column for all rows and finally alter it to not null.

Comment: @shadow, as I've pointed out in my answer you can, if you specify a `DEFAULT`...

Comment: @Shnugo That's true! Nice!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to add a `NOT NULL` column you must specify a `DEFAULT`:

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable 
    ADD SomeColumn INT NOT NULL 
    CONSTRAINT DF_YourTable_SomeColumn DEFAULT(0);
```

Other possibility is to add it with `NULL`, add your data and alter it to `NOT NULL` later (see ALTER TABLE)

EDIT: Your comment about "how to insert values"...

This depends very much in your needs. If you want to set all rows to the same value it is:

```
UPDATE YourTable SET SomeColumn=0;
```

Comment: then how to insert values in that column ??

Comment: @RahulSirohi, edited my answer... This is **absolute base knowledge** actually. So please use one of the millions of tutorials you'll find out there...

Comment: if i want to add different values ?

Comment: @RahulSirohi, really... How should I answer this without any knowledge about your data table and its content??? If there is a `unique key` (might be a `primary key`) you can set each row separately with `UPDATE YourTable SET SomeColumn=aValue WHERE TheKey=123;`